# Laravel/angular - 400 bad request

Tags: php, angularjs, api, laravel

I am making an app in ionic and the backend is made in Laravel. I am working on a password reset functionality, and I keep getting the above mentioned error, when I am testing endpoints in chrome. This is the code for the contact information function:

```
    sendContactConfirmation: function(contact, reset) {
      var defer = $q.defer();

      if(reset == 'reset'){
        var endpointUrl = $http.post(AppSettings.apiUrl + "/users/reset", { phone: contact });
      }
      else {
        var endpointUrl = $http.post(AppSettings.apiUrl + "/users", { phone: contact });
      }

      endpointUrl.then(function(result) {
        service.set(result.data.user);
        defer.resolve(result);
      }, function(error) {
        defer.reject(error);
      });

      return defer.promise;
    },
```

And these are the routes in my Laravel back-end:

```
Route::group(['jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate']], 'prefix' => 'api', 'namespace' => 'Api'], function() {
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
    Route::get('authenticate/user', 'AuthenticateController@getAuthenticatedUser');

    Route::post('users', 'UsersController@register');
    Route::post('users/reset', 'UsersController@resetContact');
    Route::put('users/{user}/reset', 'UsersController@resetPassword');
    Route::put('users/{user}', 'UsersController@update');
    Route::put('users/{user}/activate', 'UsersController@activate');
    Route::post('users/{user}/pic', 'UsersController@uploadPicture');
});
```

And this is the resetContact function:

```
public function resetContact(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(
            $request,
            ['phone' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]{8}$/']
        );

        $user = User::where('phone', $request->get('phone'))->firstOrFail();

        if ($user) {
            try {

                $this->sendValidationCode($user, 'reset');
            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new ApiException($e->getMessage(), 500);
            }
        }

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }
```

Not sure why do I get this 400 Bad request error for this.

Comment: how are you testing the end-points in chrome exactly? postman?

Comment: Can you paste here the response on that 400 call?... You can see in the network section on the developer console in your browser

Answer (score 0):

When using Laravel JWT make sure you always send the token for all routes under jwt.auth otherwise you will get the error 400 = Token not provided. In ionic make sure your toke is provided on each call to your laravel endpoint to avoid this error.